# Simple Asynchronous Multi-Threaded HTTP request library for C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, client-server

I'll be quick and honest: I'm currently trying to write a client/server for an online game. Since I'm poor and limited on resources, I'll be testing the bare basics of the server using a PHP backend, with the eventual goal being to rebuild the server end in C++.

I'm looking for a C++ library for Windows (XP and Vista preferably) that will let me use a finite number of threads, one dedicated to each piece of the networking problem. As an example, I want to use a thread to report the positional information of the player to the server (and to receive responses about positional information of the other players) but I want a different thread to background download in the 3D artwork for the area/players, and a different thread for the built in chat system, etc. These all need to be fairly independent of one another.

I know what I want to *do* with the library, I've got the design bit figured out, I just feel a bit silly re-inventing the wheel, since I know that a good library for this exact purpose probably already exists. So, what are your suggestions? I need to be able to send data to a server, and accept responses. Ideally, the request needs to trigger an Event when its done (so I can immediately grab the data and do something with it) and I need to be able to handle multiple transactions simultaneously. HTTP is a nice bonus, but I can handle HTTP protocol myself if necessary, especially considering that I plan on dropping it in the long run.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

ASIO has simple web server examples.

[Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html)

Comment: using curl would be waaay simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/poco/info/) library. It has a multithreaded TCP server and a HTTPserver.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries, in particular, Boost [Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Comment: Boost seems to be coming up a lot recently. Alright, time to try a grand experiment. (Good thing the project is just started, its easy to do at this point.) Yay!

Answer (score 1):

You can try my [CSocksetServer](http://networkdls.com/Software.Asp?Review=23) class. It can handle many connections in separate threads and supplies you with lots of different events. While it doesn’t have native HTTP capabilities, I have built web servers with it.

Answer (score -2):

You should just use [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se/) with multihandles. It is better designed to do what you want than whatever it is that you have designed.