# What C++ library should I use to implement a HTTP client?

Tags: c++, http, client

I'm looking for a C++ library that implements or enables the implementation of a HTTP client. It should handle cookies as well.

What would you propose?

Comment: duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342918/simple-asynchronous-multi-threaded-http-request-library-for-c

Comment: imho no, that is ANOTHER question (asyncronous library, threading)

Comment: Have a look at this nice list : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

Comment: simple http client 
https://github.com/pedro-vicente/lib_netsockets/blob/master/examples/http_client.cc

Comment: [Boost.Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Curl++](http://www.curlpp.org/):  is an option, particularly if you want things in more of a C++ style.

[cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/#): very good and simple to use, available on ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libcppnetlib-dev
```

example:

```
using namespace boost::network;
using namespace boost::network::http;

client::request request_("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
request_ << header("Connection", "close");
client client_;
client::response response_ = client_.get(request_);
std::string body_ = body(response_);
```

Comment: What does the ending underscore convention indicate?

Comment: @rbanffy sometimes it's used for private members but more often just to avoid name collisions (especially with keywords)

Comment: `Unable to locate package libcppnetlib-dev` on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Don't forget cpp20-http-client: https://github.com/avocadoboi/cpp20-http-client

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at [Poco Libraries](http://pocoproject.org/).

I started using them as they are portable and it's a joy to work with. Simple and clean - though I haven't dived in anything fancy for the moment.

Comment: Poco is a very nice library that in my opinion deserves more publicity than it seems to get

Comment: Poco seems obsolete since C++11 came out, with its own non-standard shared pointers, and not taking advantage of "new" C++ features that would make for a better API.

Comment: Poco HTTP client is synchronous

Comment: I just went through the extreme pain of using the Poco HTTP client. To do something relatively simple it took 33 lines of code. I know C++ isn't concise, but I'm totally spoiled by newer languages at this point where it would have been 3 lines of code at most, and I wouldn't have needed six includes. UGH.

Answer (score 16):

- [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)
- [libwww](http://www.w3.org/Library/)

Answer (score 12):

C++ (STL) does not have a HTTP or network library by default, you will have to do with something else.

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) should do what you want. [cURL++](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/) is the same libcurl wrapped in a shiny C++ wrapper.

Comment: Link to cURL++ appears dead

Answer (score 3):

You can try WinInet

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385331(VS.85).aspx

In contrast to WinHTTP, it's more client-side oriented.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Take a look at my comment on WinHTTP answer on this question as it applies here as well.
"// This call will fail on the first pass, because 
   // no buffer is allocated.
   if(!HttpQueryInfo(hHttp,HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,
      (LPVOID)lpOutBuffer,&dwSize,NULL))"
"For ease of use, WinINet abstracts these protocols into a high-level interface."
High-level interface?
Maybe it was high-level interface 20 years ago...

Comment: You can also look at URL monikers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774965(VS.85).aspx, 

it relies on WinInet(as I think), but provides COM like interface.

Comment: @Piotr: trust me, if you think WinHTTP is bad, you will absolutely *HATE* WinInet... It is an astonishingly unfriendly API, even if you're used to working with C libraries. And the worst part of it may be the WinInet constants and errors that "bleed through" to higher-level libraries such as MSXML... The big advantage of WinInet is that if a user has already configured proxy settings for their account (via the administrator options or the IE / Internet Options control panel) then WinInet will pick those up automatically; other libraries may need explicit configuration. Windows-only though...

Comment: and wininet could popup gui's reqiuring user to do something

Answer (score 2):

If it's for windows, take a look at  Windows HTTP Services (WinHTTP)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273(VS.85).aspx

> Microsoft Windows HTTP Services
>   (WinHTTP) provides developers with an
>   HTTP client application programming
>   interface (API) to send requests
>   through the HTTP protocol to other
>   HTTP servers.
>
> WinHTTP offers both a C/C++
>   application programming interface
>   (API) and a Component Object Model
>   (COM) automation component suitable
>   for use in Active Server Pages (ASP)
>   based applications.

For Cookies http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383261(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  
It's plain C without any of C++ there.  
I'd really like to make use of Bjarne's hard work (http://research.att.com/~bs).
It should be forbidden for a couple of years now to use C in application programming :)

Answer (score 2):

All alternative library are available here, if you need complex http APIs, try curl, if just wanna get a file, try http-tiny

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can drive IE using [`IWebBrowser2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127.aspx) interface.

Comment: Valid, but a **really** slow solution for those with high performance requirements.