# RapidXML - How to open XML file from server location?

Tags: xml, file, file-io, rapidxml

I'm having trouble reading an xml file from a server location. When the file is opened locally on the computer, it appears to work fine. However, when the file is opened from a location on a server, it does not work. Do you know what the problem may be? Am I using the forward slash incorrectly?

The following works:

```
rapidxml::file<> xmlFile("myfile.xml");
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
```

The following does not work:

```
rapidxml::file<> xmlFile("http://localhost/myfile.xml");
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
```

Comment: is the file really on the server and accessible from the browser?

Comment: Yeah. I used the same url in the browser and I am able to view the xml... I'm not sure if this is a limitation in RapidXML or if I'm using the wrong type of forward/backslashes in my string..

Comment: is it a windows server?

Comment: sorry i dont understand your comment

Comment: is it a windows server?

Comment: Yeah I am on windows 7

Comment: Do you have rapidxml? Does this work for you?

Comment: And i dont understand what the problem is, as reading the file does work as you say

Comment: If I place the file in the same directory as my cpp application, it works. But if I read the file from the server's folder (I am using Apache), it does not read the xml. I dont know if this is a rapidxml problem or if the string I am using above is incorrect

Comment: Why should you load something from localhost via http if you have it already in the filesystem on your localhost?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45418/discussion-between-user1007017-and-user1456962)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don’t you use downloader library like ‘curl’ and download to your local and use it like normal file system operation.

Comment: Hm, I would prefer to be able to read the xml directly from the server. I used the same url in the browser and I am able to view the xml... I'm not sure if this is a limitation in RapidXML or if I'm using the wrong type of forward/backslashes in my string..

Answer (score 1):

RapidXML is just an XML parser, not an HTTP client. You'll need to use an HTTP client library to retrieve a file from a URL.

Comment: Ahh I see.. I've never done something like this before (accessing a file via HTTP to retrieve a file). Do you have any suggestions on what library to use? Is there something in the standard library that I can use? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user1456962. It depends on your OS, dev tools, etc. But look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124129/high-level-http-client-library-for-native-c-c-in-win32