# What library I can use for sending POST and GET requests in C++?

Tags: c++, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What C++ library should I use to implement a HTTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822581/what-c-library-should-i-use-to-implement-a-http-client)

What library I can use for sending POST and GET requests in C++

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822581/what-c-library-should-i-use-to-implement-a-http-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or its c++ wrapper [curlpp](http://curlpp.org/)

Answer (score 5):

libcurl

http://curl.haxx.se/

It works and is really simple.

Answer (score 2):

what about cpp-netlib?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-netlib/