# Simpliest way to send http package on Windows and Mac

Tags: c++, http, plugins

I have no expirience with C++, and I need to develop a plugin for an app written on C++ (for both its Windows and MacOS versions). The question is: what c++ lib dealing with HTTP(availible on Mac and Windows) you recomend to work with? Note that I do not need some extra functionality, simplicity is much more important.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is the one that you are looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What C++ library should I use to implement a HTTP client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822581/what-c-library-should-i-use-to-implement-a-http-client)

Comment: No, that's not just the same. The problem here is that I need a lib for both Win and Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

libcurl is a C-based library that has a reasonably simple API that can be used from C++ as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use **[cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/)**