# send image bytes from c++ client to python server

Tags: python, c++, image, byte

I want to read an image on c++ client and send its bytes to python server via post request, which shall then read those bytes of images and convert it into ndarray, can someone help with the code snippet?

Comment: We are not here to solve your homework. Please, let us know what you have done so far, i.e. show us your code so far. You can convert image to Base64 format, send that via POST request and process it on server side.

Comment: show your code and full error message.

Comment: you should start with Google "C++ http client". One of the link [What C++ library should I use to implement a HTTP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822581/what-c-library-should-i-use-to-implement-a-http-client)